# mongo findAndUpdateOne failed in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Was trying to do an restful update.

my model.js

```
module.exports.updateGenre = function (id, genre, callback) {
    var query = {_id: id};
    var update = {
        name: genre.name
    }
    Genre.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option, callback);
}
```

my route.js

```
app.put('/api/genres/:_id',function(req,res){
    var id = req.params._id;
    var genre = req.body;
    Genres.updateGenre(id, genre, null, function(err,genre){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genre)
    })
});
```

I got error of `option is not define`. But I already use null in route, I wonder it's an error. I also tried {} besides null.

Comment: Well it is not defined. Your outer signature has no option to pass in, and it has not been defined within your own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `option` argument to your `updateGenre` function:

```
module.exports.updateGenre = function (id, genre, option, callback) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the `option` argument to your module's signature. Currently it's:

```
module.exports.updateGenre = function (id, genre, callback) {
```

Add `option` to so it looks like:

```
module.exports.updateGenre = function (id, genre, option, callback) {
```

Comment: ah what a careless miskate! thanks!